# D3.js Observable Force Layout, Labels not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My **[force layout](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph)** code is standard, based of the usual [data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/5916d145c8c048a6e3086915a6be464467391c62/miserables.json):

```
chart = {
  const links = data.links.map(d => Object.create(d));
  const nodes = data.nodes.map(d => Object.create(d));

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(function(d) {return d.value;}).strength(0.1))

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

  const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#999")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .join("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.id));

  const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", color)
      .call(drag(simulation));

  var lables = node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3);

  node.append("title")
      .text(d => d.id);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  });

  invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());

  return svg.node();
}
```

I am **trying to add labels** to each node. Note the label code above. This adds the labels to the node element (confirmed by browser console), but the labels do not appear:

[image]

Since D3 doesn't support z-index the order of adding elements is obviously wrong. How can I make the labels appear on each node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://observablehq.com/@garciaguillermoa/force-directed-graph) is the updated Observable.

The problem was that you were adding the text "inside" the `circle` and that is not possible in an SVG. The solution is to create a `group` instead of a `circle`, use `translate` instead `cx` and `cy` in the `tick` function, and finally, create the `circle` and the `text` inside the `group`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I notice you use .selectAll(".node") ... how do we know a class called node exists? Is this just always available in a D3 visual with nodes?

Comment: No, it is not always available, it doesn't exists, that is my mistake, I am sorry about that. If we try to update the nodes using that code, it won't work. In order to fix it, we could add .attr('class', 'node') to the 'g' in the ' join' method. I have just updated the Observable and fixed it.