# D3 adding labels to forced graph nodes

Tags: d3.js, directed-graph

I am trying to use the code at http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239. Additional thing I need with this is to have labels with each node. I am trying like :

```
node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.size?"":" leaf"); })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size ? d.size + dr : dr+1; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .on("click", function(d) {
console.log("node click", d, arguments, this, expand[d.group]);
        expand[d.group] = !expand[d.group];
    init();
      })

node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".3em").text("Node Name To Display")
```

But this does not work.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172926/d3-js-observable-force-layout-labels-not-appearing/57173483#57173483

Comment: I am looking for some small fix within this code http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239. would that be possible ?